# calculating objects height from video by knowing the homography in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality, homography

I'm trying to measure the heights of the objects detected in my tracking application I'm developing using OpenCV and Python. I've calculated the homography matrix so I know every object's location in the real world and it's apparent height on the video frame. What I don't know is the real world position of the camera. I've seen that the camera pose matrix can be calculated from the homography, but I'm not sure what to do with that.

The video is recorded from head level and the objects are mostly people. The homography transforms the camera pixels to the ground level.

The width of the objects can be measured by transforming the leftmost and rightmost coordinates to real world coordinates and measuring the distance between them. How can I calculate the height?

Comment: You need to be much more clear about what you do and do not know.  For instance, what do you mean by "I know every object's location in the real world"?  Do you mean relative to the camera or relative to some world origin?  Also why can't you use the exact same procedure you use to calculate width to calculate height?  If you rotate your camera 90 degrees all the widths become heights anyway...

Comment: I know every objects location relative to a world origin. I calculate that by knowing the homography. I cannot rotate the camera, because I'm using video files.

Comment: My point isn't that rotating the camera solves your problem, it is that I don't understand what the effective difference is between heights and widths.  Both are just distance measurements in the x-y plane

Comment: You're right, this wasn't clear. I extended the question. My x-y plane is on the ground, so only width can be measured on that. Height would be z.

Comment: ok, can your question be simplified to this:  Given a point in an image xim and yim and a known coordinate xworld or yworld corresponding to that image point how can I find zworld ?  Also is your camera calibrated?

Comment: Extrinsic parameters are calibrated, distortions are not, but it can be done in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute vanishing points and cross ratio use then.
You can find more here:
http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse590ss/01wi/notes/projective.ppt